# How to iterate through a nested array in a Mongo collection

Tags: arrays, mongodb, meteor, reactjs

I've been trying to figure this out for hours now. Basically this is my issue:

I am trying to iterate through a nested array. I have a collection called "Categories" in which these is a field called Agents[]. I need to display the list of these Agents. This is my current code:

```
 return (

      <div>
        {Categories2.find({name: Session.get("catName")}, {Agents: 1}).fetch().map((category)=> {



          if (category.Agents.length == 0){
            return (<div>No Agents Exist Yet</div>);
          }



          tempVarEmail= category.Agents[count].email;
          console.log (tempVarEmail + " " + count);
          count++;

          tempVarId = category.name;



        return(

              <li>{tempVarEmail} <a className="right-align" onClick={this.removeAgent.bind(this)}> x </a></li>

        )




        })}




      </div>)
```

I am assuming I need to nested map() function or something but I cannot get the syntax correct. This only displays the first Agent in the category because that's exactly what it tells it to.

Any help?

Comment: Can you post the nested map function you tried?

Comment: please post the sample (or all of it) inout document, what your query looks like now, and how the resulting document should look like once the query is run. this way, writing a sample query would be easier.

Comment: @erichardson30 I have given up on it because it was so messy and my page wouldn't even render.

Comment: @JBone I'm not sure I understand. If category.Agent has 3 fields of test@agent1.com test@agent2.com and test@agent3.com I want them all to be displayed in the <li>